# Setting correct Y-axis labels from column names for boxplots using loops

Tags: r, for-loop, boxplot

I have a data frame (data2) with multiple columns as variables. I ran the code below to create individual boxplots but my problem is the y-axis labels are labeled as "i" instead of the column names for each boxplot. How do I fix this?

sample of first 6 rows and first 7 columns below.

```
for (i in data2[,c(5:36)]{
          boxplot(i ~ data2$cv,
                  xlab = "CV")
    }



 block loc cv rep days_til_flower days_til_anthesis days_til_harvest
1     1 H12 CR   1               9                21               59
2     1 H12 CR   2               7                20               57
3     1 H12 LB   1               7                20               62
4     1 H12 LB   2              13                21               62
5     1 H12 YC   1               7                17               59
6     1 H12 YC   2               7                16               59
```

Comment: Please, share a sample of your data with dput(), so we can make a reproductible example

Comment: added a sample of my data in my original post, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for exactly, but here's how I would do it with the `mtcars` data:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in c(1,3,4,5,6,7)){
  boxplot(mtcars[,i] ~ mtcars$am, xlab="American", ylab = names(mtcars)[i])
}
```

[image]